# Can I use electrical tape to fix a damaged wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

While assembling a treadmill, I screwed through one of its wires (pretty sure it's the I/O cable).  Can I fix this with electrical tape, or do I need to get this repaired?  Any advice is much appreciated!

[image]
(click to enlarge image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure you only damaged the outer insulation of an I/O cable then electrical tape would be Ok. If any other cable insulation or conductors are at all damaged, then you should get it repaired or get a replacement cable. Treadmills can be dangerous so you don't want to take chances with them malfunctioning or the dead man switch not working.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  The screw went through the insulation and likely the conductors - I could see through to the other side.  Since it's probably involved in treadmill controls, I'll get it repaired.

Comment: if you can see any metal in the hole, don't use tape, otherwise it's probably ok.

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be a data cable.

data is normally low voltage and electrical tape would be fine starting 1/2” or more away make a tight wrap over coating at least 1/2 with each additional wrap will provide plenty of insulation for this.

The NEC doesn’t deal with equipment but having worked for a large company that was the method used to repair skinned cables.

If copper is showing on multiple conductors sealing then protecting with tape is preformed for field repairs.

Comment: +1... definitely strip (carefully!) the outer sheath to see what has happened to the interior wires.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  I wrapped it with electrical tape for now.